# Is there a way to integrate grails with webcomponents technolgy (like Polymer)?

Tags: grails, polymer, web-component

After google it. I found that there isn't a grails plugin to use in my grails application.

However, I think it is not as complicated as it sounds.

Does anyone have idea where I could start ?

Comment: Polymer is just a collection of JS and HTML files, right? Then just add them to your Grails app and start using them. Nothing special here at all. You /could/ create a plugin that provides those assets but that isn't required. You will have to do some configuration to serve the static assets through asset-pipeline but that's not too difficult.

Comment: As i think @JoshuaMoore. As i think JoshuaMoore. I just have to make some configurations in the server. I'll go ahead in that way.

Comment: You could start with examples at polymer-project.org, e.g. http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-elements/demo.html#paper-checkbox

Comment: @JotaB how are you using Polymer? Do you use asset plugin and manually install the files from the polymer zip file in the asset folder? Or did you use bower to install it in the asset folder?

Comment: I just tried Polymer and I find it easiest to use Bower. I created a folder extras in assets folder and install Polymer and elements I need.